# calculate a colliding key to a given hash using a specific hash function

Tags: hash

Given the following hash function (written in java):

```
long hash(String key) {
    char[] c = key.toCharArray();
    long hash = 7;
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        hash = hash*31 + c[i];
    }
    return hash;
}
```

(note: I would have put the type of this hash function in the question title but couldn't find out what it's called. If you know the term please let me know in the comments)

How can one compute a key that gets hashed to the same value as some other key?

```
long a = hash("myKey");
String x = reverseHash(a);
assert(hash(x) == a);
```

Is there a way to compute this efficiently? (not looking for a decryption algorithm, only for a way to produce an equivalent hash)

How would such an algorithm look like? (doesn't have to use the exact same numbers as my example, I just want to understand it)

Comment: You're looking to create a *collision* on that hash function. *"not looking for a decryption algorithm*" of course not, because there is no encryption involved here. A hash is very different from an encryption algorithm.

Comment: you're totally right! I just wanted to make things clear because I found so many how-to-decrypt-questions while researching.

Comment: Consider a 2-byte key, you would effectively have `7*31*31+b1*31+b2`, so simply calculate this and then solve for a different value of b1 or b2. If you then make these bytes the first 2 bytes in any sized key, you can generate collisions. So for instance, if you increase the first character by 1, you need to decrease the second character by 31, to make a matching hash. (for this particular has function)